# Configuration of $n$ lines on the plane: reference

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, reference-request, discrete-geometry

Suppose that given $n$ lines on the plane with no three concurrent and no two parallel. Then, there are a lot of well-known results about that configuration (number of regions formed by these lines, minimal number of triangles, minimal and maximal number of infinite regions and so on).

Are there any books or articles, where I can find more results and can learn more about this topic?

It seems to me that this should be closely related to discrete geometry, but I don't know where to start searchng.